# Creating ssh connections between AWS instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2

I have two Ubuntu instances (A, B) sitting in a test AWS environment. The app I'm working on uses an rsync command to move files from A to B and so in order to do this, I normally (Vagrant locally) have a script that uses ssh-copy-id to copy A's public key to B. The rsync happens in the background on A, so it's local user would be "root", but transfers to the standard "ubuntu" user on B.

This has worked no issues at all on my dev platform, albeit that I don't use public keys for SSH access on the dev platform and different usernames for the credentials.

In AWS I understand that things are a little different, that the default username for my servers would be "ubuntu" etc etc but I'm still having issues getting A's root public key to work correctly on B.

This is what I'm doing (please note prefix showing when I'm using root and non-root users):

```
serverA:# ssh-keygen -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa -P "" -b 1024 -C ""
serverA:# more /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

(Copy content to clipboard)

```
serverB:$ vi ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

(Paste content to end of file)

```
serverB:$ sudo service ssh restart
```

It's at this point I was under the impression that all should be working so back on serverA I at least attempt an SSH connection:

```
serverA:# ssh ubuntu@serverB_ip_address
```

I'd already updated security groups so I get prompted to confirm the fingerprint, which I do, but I'm still getting:

```
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong here??

Comment: Has the identity been added to your user-agent? `ssh-add -l` to list, omit the `-l` to add your keys.

Comment: Are you forwarding your ssh agent ? I might not be the direct cause, but sometimes it can help when you have `Permission denied (publickey)`

Comment: When all else fails, you can use `ssh ... -vvv` to enable a high level of verbose logging, to see which keys are presented when, and when the server rejects the connection.

Comment: @MattClark good point, so on serverA I ran `ssh-add` reports back "Could not open a connection to your authenticate agent". Ok, so `eval ssh-agent -s` (using backticks which aren't shown here) reports back a pid#, and then `ssh-add` successfully adds id_rsa. I do the same on serverB and all appears fine ... but still no dice. On serverB I performed `ssh-add` for both root and ubuntu users, same thing.

Comment: Is key auth enabled by your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`? `RSAAuthentication yes` && `PubkeyAuthentication yes` && `RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes`. To show \`'s, they must be escaped.

Comment: `RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
#AuthorizedKeysFile     %h/.ssh/authorized_keys`

Now the last line looks suspicious, but I thought that it must be working otherwise how'd I get SSH access to the instances in the first place? However, I uncommented it, restarted the service, and still no banana

(Did you mean to copy the config twice in your last post?)

Comment: Can you double check that id_rsa.pub on serverA and authorized_keys on serverB are the same. Use something like cksum to check ? I ask for this cause i got the same case this week and that was the mistake.... If the same, try ssh -vvv

Comment: It seems there is a discrepancy in the 'user' you are trying to login as. If you are trying to login as **'ubuntu'**, you need to update the authorized_keys in ```/home/ubuntu/.ssh/authorized_keys```. If you are trying to login as **'root'**, you need to update the authorized_keys in ```/root/.ssh/authorized_keys```